# Parse in-project string like CLI arguments in Python

Tags: python, getopt

Is there a way to parse string as CLI arguments in Python?

I want to parse importing line in python code say:

```
from x import y as z
```

I want to transform it into a string like

```
-f x -i y -a z
```

and access values using arguments names

How can I achieve it?

I tried code like this

```
opt, args = getopt.getopt('-f x -i y -a z', 'f:i:z:')
```

but it just pushes parameters string into args

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple 'translator' like the below

```
lookup = {'from':'-f','import':'-i','as':'-a'}
data = 'from x import y as z'
translated = ' '.join(lookup.get(x,x) for x in data.split())
print(translated)
```

output

```
-f x -i y -a z
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i asked for. I want to push this output into dictionary for example. And also numbered arguments wont work for me as i want to process other string like 'import os, sys'

Comment: How should the dict look like ? Please explain the actual use case.

Comment: {'-f' : 'x', '-i' : 'y', '-a':'z' }